# AngularJS and getting window scroll position in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll

I'm having some trouble understanding how to get the scroll position of window within my controller, so I can build logic around it.

From all the questions and answers I've been reading the most accepted answer seems to be to write a directive that calculates the scroll position, stick that directive on an element, and that's it.

However, when you want to do something along the lines of:

```
if (scrollY > 100 ){
  $scope.showMenu = true;
}

if (scrollY > 500) {
  $scope.showFooter = true;
}
```

This approach doesn't seem to work, because the calculated position in the directive can't be accessed from the controller. What would be the right 'Angular' way of doing this, which would still allow slightly more complicated logic to be executed from the controller?

Comment: Bind the controller's scope variable to the directive's isolated scope and implement the logic in the directive's controller.

Comment: @Angad, Linial, would it be possible to illustrate this with an example? Please? :)

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253322/angular-js-scroll-window

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to @RobKohr comment, here's a optimized approach using `.on('scroll')` and `$scope.$apply` to update a scope element on scroll.

```
$document.on('scroll', function() {
    // do your things like logging the Y-axis
    console.log($window.scrollY);

    // or pass this to the scope
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.pixelsScrolled = $window.scrollY;
    })
});
```

Comment: You'll receive more granularity on the scroll position because it's responding to the native scroll event, but you're going to be thrashing the angular scope by `$applying` that every time the handler fires. This is definitely not optimized. Instead refer to my comment in response to RobKhor: `requestAnimationFrame` is the way to go. Avoid touching the scope at all costs!

Comment: As far as I remember, I was needed `$scope.pixelsScrolled` in many places of my website and this allowed me to make it maintainable and I kept good performances for what I've asked.

Comment: But if ever someone has performances issues, he can still attach any logic (like RAF) where the `console.log` is on my snippet.

Answer (score 7):

Inject the `$window` service into your controller, which is simply a wrapper around the browser `window` object, and you have the `$window.scrollX` and `$window.scrollY` properties.

If you want to respond to changes in scroll, put a watch on them:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return $window.scrollY;
}, function (scrollY) {
    /* logic */
});
```

Comment: Worked for me. A little slow though. It doesn't seem to update frequently

Comment: @RobKohr Agreed. The question hints at setting a scope variable when the scroll position changes, so a `$scope.$watch` made the most sense, but I should have also mentioned that `requestAnimationFrame` should be used for paint operations like this. In that case, any changes to scope variables should be wrapped inside a `$scope.$apply` function, or they won't be picked up by Angular - a small inconvenience for the increased efficiency of `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: @SimonRobb When I compare `$window.scrollY` to my `angular.element(...).prop('offsetTop')`, they are vastly out of alignment. When I scroll on the page down to the element, `$window.scrollY` shows `1552` and `prop('offsetTop')` shows `2013` even though I've arrived at that element. How do I get these to align?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer lacks teardown code:

> ERRONEOUS (lacks teardown)
>
> ```
> $document.on('scroll', function() {
>     // do your things like logging the Y-axis
>     console.log($window.scrollY);
>
>    // or pass this to the scope
>     $scope.$apply(function() {
>         $scope.pixelsScrolled = $window.scrollY;
>     })
> });
> ```

To avoid memory leaks and other undesired behavior, the code needs to do proper teardown when the `$scope` is destroyed.

```
$document.on('scroll', scrollHandler);

$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    $document.off('scroll', scrollHandler);
});

function scrollHandler(ev) {
    // do your things like logging the Y-axis
    console.log($window.scrollY);

    // or pass this to the scope
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.pixelsScrolled = $window.scrollY;
    });
}
```