# Scrollposition mix of vm and scope

Tags: angularjs

I have used some code I found here on stack for scrollposition, it works great, but now I have a mix of vm (controller as) and $scope.

How do I get rid of $scope for this code? There is a function inside of document.on, but if I change it, vm seems to be undefined.
What is this type of context called, where I have to pass scope into the function like this?

```js
(function () {
 'use strict';

 angular.module('App').controller('BaseCtrl', ['$document', '$window','$scope', function ($document, $window,$scope) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.topMenuClass = "scene-topheader_largeLogo";

  $document.on('scroll', function () {
   // or pass this to the scope
   $scope.$apply(function () {
    if ($window.scrollY > 100) {
     vm.topMenuClass = "scene-topheader_smallLogo";
    }

    if ($window.scrollY < 70) {
     vm.topMenuClass = "scene-topheader_largeLogo";
    }
   });
  });

 }]);
 //end
}());
```

Comment: Does `vm.topMenuClass` feed an `ng-class` directive? If so, the entire functionality could be moved into a custom directive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes it's for ng-class. OK. I will move it to a directive.

I found it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365339/angularjs-and-getting-window-scroll-position-in-controller.

Comment: The code lacks proper teardown. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56726639/5535245 for an explaination on how to do proper teardown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is this type of context called, where I have to pass scope into the function like this?

From the Docs:

> AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.
>
> You can also use `$apply()` to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript. Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) `$apply` has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is **needed only when implementing custom event callbacks**, or when working with third-party library callbacks.
>
> [image]

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the Browser Event Loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

Comment: Thank you. I understand it much better now.