# AngularJS - Does scrolling to an element belong in a directive?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm well aware that DOM manipulation belongs in directives rather than controllers, but I'm hung up on whether simply scrolling to an element (with jQuery's `scrollTop`) would be considered DOM manipulation and/or should be moved into a directive.

My page is dynamically generated (using Grails) and a small bootstrap dropdown is placed on the corner of the page to facilitate scrolling to places within the lengthy document:

```
<a ng-click="scrollTo('question${ subQuestion.id}')">
```

The `${}` is replaced with a number when sent to the client.

My `scrollTo` function within my controller is rather simple and works:

```
$scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + id).offset().top - 50
    }, 1000);
};
```

I'm using ui-router and was previously using `$uiViewScroll` to scroll to the element; this seemed more in line with the *angular way* but I need the 50px offset because of a navigation bar and I prefer the animation (both don't seem to be an option with `$uiViewScroll`).

---

My questions:

- Does scrolling to an element have any digest consequences like a true DOM manipulation?
- Is scrolling to an element outside of a directive a bad practice? If so, why?

Comment: `$anchorScoll` has offset option and `$uiViewScroll` can be set to use `$anchorScoll`

Answer (score 1):

- Scrolling runs outside of the normal digest cycle, see this thread [How can I hide an element when the page is scrolled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253322/angular-js-scroll-window)
- I would say it is bad practice since it includes references to elements in the DOM, but that's just me... :-) Perhaps it can make testing the controller a bit harder since you need to handle the `$`.