# when scrolled $(window) scroll function not triggered at angular controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to fix some new panel when window is scrolled but, whenever I scrolled window then `$(window).scroll(fucntion(){ });` is not triggered. This function is in my angular controller.

This is at angular controller but when I scroll it isn't triggered

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
            console.log(" i Like it");
        //$scope.$apply();
    });
```

I also tried this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(window).scroll(function () {
            console.log(" i Like it");
        //$scope.$apply();
    });
});
```

But it's also not working.
Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253322/angular-js-scroll-window
or https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

Answer (score 1):

May I ask why are you using parenthesis? ($(window))

Please try following code:

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("ctrl", function ($window) {
  var i = 0;

    $window.onscroll = function(){
     console.log(" i Like it: " + i++);
   };
});
```

Should be triggered by window scroll.
But honestly you should really consider the use of directives instead.

Comment: please also add the $window as dependency of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

when you work with angular you have to think about separation of concerns. You shouldn't add this kind of functionality inside of an angular controller. If you want to do something with the DOM probably you should use an angular directive.

Regards