# AngularJS window scroll event does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I know there are some similar question concerning this problem, however I none of the solutions could help me.

I am using AngularJS and want to detect the scroll event. I tried plenty of versions on how to get the event, however at most it fires when first loaded then never again.

My last code I tried was the following:

```
$($window).on('scroll', alert('scrolled'));
```

But I also tried this:

- [Jquery .on('scroll') not firing the event while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375636/jquery-onscroll-not-firing-the-event-while-scrolling)
- or just the simple JQuery .scroll() event
- window.onscroll = function(ev) ...

and many more, but nothing works.

Can anyone tell my what I am doing wrong?

Update: I tried the directive stuff, this works perfectly fine with safari BUT however not with chrome. Whats going on?

Update2: It works with the chrome mobile view when using the shift key. Are there any restrictions on chrome to apple trackpad? WTF?

Comment: I think it could depend on where you are using this code. In a controller, in the directive link, etc. Can you post some more code?

Comment: The dom is probably not ready at the point you're adding the event listener. Add it in a directive's link method and it should work. Please have a look at the answer to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253322/angular-js-scroll-window).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just use

```
$(window).scroll(function () { alert('scrolled') })
```

OR you could use

```
angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function(e) {
    alert('scrolled')
})
```

Comment: Angular has some built in jquery functionality using angular.element

Comment: okay that works with Safari, however NOT with chrome. Any idea why this is so & how so fix it?

Comment: Try using a directive as shown in the jsfiddle. This will ensure your listener isn't created too late or too early.

Answer (score 3):

there is no need for angular.element()
inject $window to your controller,
use the window.onscroll event

`$window.onscroll = function (){
    console.log('window was scrolled!');
};`