# $window is not triggering on scroll in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When we scroll down the `$window` function is not triggering. Can someone help me out? Actually the issue is, when user scrolls down a button should appear. When user hits that button the scroll bar needs to go up same like back to top functionality.

#### JavaScript Code:

```
app.controller('appCrtl', ['$scope', '$window', function('$scope', '$window') {

  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(scroll);
    if (scroll > 500 || scroll == undefined) {
      $scope.showUpArrow = false;
    } else {
      $scope.showUpArrow = true;
    }
  });
}]);
```

Comment: You are not using angular $window, you are using jquery: $(window) is not the same as $window, see this answer, maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014728/angularjs-window-scroll-event-does-not-fire

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS window scroll event does not fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014728/angularjs-window-scroll-event-does-not-fire)

Comment: Any feedback? Are you going to mark an answer as the right one?

Answer (score 2):

I found a few problems with your code, specially when binding the scroll event, in angular, you make use of `angular.element` to bind events to the DOM similarly to jQuery (it's jQLite, which is a light implementation of jQuery).

```
angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function () {});
```

Also, as per you are using `$scope` out of angular context, you have to surround scope operations with `$scope.$apply(function () {});`, which will grantee the digestion of that part of the code that is outside of angular.

```
angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        // do scope stuff here
    });
});
```

Finally, you can use the `pageYOffset` property to toggle the visibility of your back to top button.

I've made an example using your code in order to demonstrate the usage of what I described before.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('appCrtl', [
    '$scope',
    '$window',
    AppCtrl
  ]);

function AppCtrl($scope, $window) {

  $scope.goToTop = function() {
    $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  };

  angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function(event) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      var scroll = $scope.scroll = this.pageYOffset;

      if (scroll > 100 || scroll == undefined) {
        $scope.showUpArrow = true;
      } else {
        $scope.showUpArrow = false;
      }
    });
  });
};
```

```css
.floating {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.display {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

.spacer {
  padding: 10px 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCrtl">

  <div class="display">scrollY: {{ scroll }}</div>
  <button class="floating" ng-show="showUpArrow" ng-click="goToTop()">^</button>

  <div class="spacer">
    <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

    <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci,
      sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

    <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

    <ol>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    </ol>

    <blockquote>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus
        turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    </ul>

    <pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix jQuery with AngularJS in that way you try it. Just use `angular.element()` to bind your scroll event like in this [**demo plnkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ym3QEdultMhYcuio3l7q?p=preview). I also alowed myself to minify your `if` / `else` condition in a single line.

---

## A simple solution to make it work in a nice way:

You are able to achieve what you try with simple codes. AngularJS is very kind to such logic.

#### Application:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope, $window) {

  $scope.showUpArrow = false;

  angular.element($window).on('scroll', function () {
      $scope.showUpArrow = $window.scrollY > 500;
      $scope.$apply();
  });

  $scope.goTop = function() {
    $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  };
});
```

#### View:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ApplicationController">
    <div class="row">
      <button class="btn-top" 
              ng-click="goTop()"
              ng-if="showUpArrow">Scroll top</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**---> [demo plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ym3QEdultMhYcuio3l7q?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

`$(window).scroll(function (event) {` is wrong syntax, you're using Angularjs, not jQuery. The correct part should be:

```
angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function(e) {
  // do stuff 
});
```

And updated code from the question:

```
app.controller('appCrtl' ,['$scope','$window', function('$scope','$window') {
  angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function(e) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(scroll);
    if(scroll>500 || scroll==undefined) {
      $scope.showUpArrow = false;
    } else {
      $scope.showUpArrow = true;
    }
  });
}]);
```

Comment: should i need to inject $window in controller ?

Comment: Sure, you should inject it. If you are using `$scope` in controller, you should inject it, for `$window` and many other things we have the same rules